# Primavera Filter still Showing Activities Passed the Specified Date

Tags: planning, primavera

I can't find the solution to filter based on the range date I wanted. As I applied the filter, activities beyond the range specified is still showing.

This is the filter I tried for the range from the 5th week to 4 month from the Data Date.

[image]